# Shortest path using wave planner?

Tags: theory, mapping

How could I compute the shortest path between point a and b using wave planner?

I don't see how using the wave planner would give me the shortest; it would just give me a path! As far as I can tell, I would only be able to give a random path to the destination, but nothing else than that.

Comment: What's a _wave planner_? Could you provide a link, for example to Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

According to this website http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150IR/labs/wavefront.html
It shows a method of converting the zero to number and calculating the fastest distance.I am assuming you mean wavefront instead of wave planning